# Force Rsync to update the modification time of each file it moves?

Tags: rsync, backup

`rsync --delete` makes me nervous, so instead I'm using the following command line to move the files to a trash folder instead:

```
rsync -vr --no-t --stats --existing --ignore-existing --delete --backup --backup-dir="$trash" . "$output"
```

What I would like to do is update the modification time of each file moved to the trash so that I can delete the oldest files from the trash when the backup drive is 90% full. However I can't seem to get rsync to actually update the modification time.

Comment: The solution I use: You could just backup to a series of subdirectories under trash/ and delete the oldest subdir as needed. (I name the subfolders with a date, but you can do just sequenced or whatever).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson That was actually my first idea for this script, but I thought it would less messy to force rsync to update modification times instead. Oh well.

Comment: I'm probably going to end up redoing this whole thing in python anyway. If a folder is renamed, rsync insists on re-transferring the whole thing instead of just tracking down where the folder went to and renaming it at the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync will maintain the original `mtime` for the backed-up fails, but the `ctime` will show the time you want.

You can view `ctime` with `ls -c`, or `stat`, and search for them with `find` and `-ctime` or `-cnewer`.